# Implementing multiple instances of the same generic Java interface with different generic types?

Tags: java, generics

I am designing an event-driven system and am running into some basic API problems regarding generics.

I woud like all events to extend `BaseEvent`:

```
// Groovy pseudo-code
abstract BaseEvent {
    Date occurredOn

    BaseEvent() {
        super()

        this.occurredOn = new Date() // Now
    }
}
```

And I would like all event listeners to implement some basal interface:

```
interface EventListener<EVENT extends BaseEvent> {
    void onEvent(EVENT event)
}
```

So this works great for simple listeners that only handle a single type of event:

```
class FizzEvent extends BaseEvent { ... }

class FizzEventListener implements EventListener<FizzEvent> {
    @Override
    void onEvent(FizzEvent fizzEvent) {
        ...
    }
}
```

But I will have some listeners that need to handle multiple types of events:

```
class BuzzEvent extends BaseEvent { ... }

// So then, ideally:
class ComplexListener implements EventListener<FizzEvent>,
        EventListener<BuzzEvent> {
    @Override
    void onEvent(FizzEvent fizzEvent) {
        ...
    }

    @Override
    void onEvent(BuzzEvent buzzEvent) {
        ...
    }
}
```

But this produces compiler errors:

> Name clash: The method onEvent(EVENT) of type EventListener has the same erasure as onEvent(EVENT) of type EventListener but does not override it

**Any ideas what the solution is for handling multiple events?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem you're running into is called *Type Erasure*, which is how Java implements generics. This means that, for Java, the following lines of code:

```
@Override
void onEvent(FizzEvent fizzEvent) {
    ...
}

@Override
void onEvent(BuzzEvent buzzEvent) {
    ...
}
```

*really* look like this:

```
@Override
void onEvent(BaseEvent fizzEvent) {
    ...
}

@Override
void onEvent(BaseEvent buzzEvent) {
    ...
}
```

Notice that the type information has been 'erased' and only the super type `BaseEvent` remains as the type parameter for *both* methods, which causes ambiguity and won't work.

If the `extends` keyword had not been used, it would only see `Object` instead, but would still run into the same problem.

This is in contrast to C#, which uses *Type Reification* to implement generics and can know the difference of types at runtime.

In other words, if you ask Java whether a `List<Dog>` is the same kind of list as a `List<Car>`, Java would say "yes" because it doesn't know any better at runtime, while C# would say "no" because it retains type information.

> Any ideas what the solution is for handling multiple events?

You will need to use different method names or signatures if you want to use the same listener interface (e.g. `onDogBarkEvent(Dog d)`, `onCatMeowEvent(Cat c)` or perhaps create separate listener interfaces for different kinds of events (e.g. `DogBarkListener`, `CatMeowListener`).

This should point you in the right direction with a few Java options.

That aside, if you really feel strongly about your choice *and* are also free to choose your programming language, then you could consider taking C# for a spin and see if it works better for you.

Answer (score 0):

a possible solution would be to skip generics and have an explicit "supports" method:

```
public FooListener implements Listener {

    public <T extends BaseEvent> boolean supports(Class<T> clazz) {
       //decide
    }

    public void handle(BaseEvent baseEvent) {
       //handle
    }
}
```

this, in combination with some abstract classes with generics for the "simple" cases, should do the trick:

```
private Class<S> clazz;

public Class<S> getClazz() {
    if(clazz==null) {
        ParameterizedType superclass = 
            (ParameterizedType)getClass().getGenericSuperclass();
        clazz = (Class<S>) superclass.getActualTypeArguments()[0];
    }
    return clazz;
}

public boolean supports(Class clazz) {
    return clazz!=null && clazz == getClazz();
```

Answer (score 0):

In java 8

```
public class ComplexListener 
{
    public final EventListener<FizzEvent> fizzListener = fizzEvent ->
    {
        ...
    }

    ...
```

use `complexListener.fizzListener` whenever an `EventListener<FizzEvent>` is needed.

(Without java8, you can use anonymous class for the same effect, just more verbose.)

Another way in java8 is through method reference

```
public class ComplexListener 
{
    public void handleFizzEvent(FizzEvent fizzListener)
    {
        ...
    }
```

use `complexListener::handleFizzEvent` whenever an `EventListener<FizzEvent>` is needed.

---

In java generics, it is explicitly forbidden that an object can be both `Foo<A>` and `Foo<B>` (A!=B); i.e. `Foo<A>` and `Foo<B>` are mutually exclusive. Many reasons can be raised, but the most important one I think is because of capture conversion -- given a `Foo<?>` object, the compiler assumes it is a `Foo<X>` of a unique `X`. Therefore no object can be `Foo<A> & Foo<B>` (irrespective of reification).