# can't Implement from generic interface in Java

Tags: java, generics

I tried to implement from generic interface twice, and I know it is not possible in java due to 'type erasure' in java generics, so I wondered how can I find a work around to solve it. this is the code I tested:

```
interface A{final static int i=3;}

interface B<T> extends A{void f(T t);}
interface D extends B<Double>{}
class C implements B<String>,D{
    public void f(String t){}
    public void f(Double t){}

}
```

so I tried wrapping  up one of the interface so that B will not be implemented twice I choose `B<Double>` and wrapped it with interface D.
Now I get another compile error: `B cannot be inherited with different arguments: <java.lang.String> and <java.lang.Double>`
anyone have another idea?
I am not sure why I am getting this compile error..

p.s- this is not the same as the thread [Implementing multiple instances of the same generic Java interface with different generic types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33535468/implementing-multiple-instances-of-the-same-generic-java-interface-with-differen)
since I can't change the name of f function as a solution. it will always collide. **is there any way to see the raw type when trying to compile?**

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Purely hypothetical questions have no meaning.

Comment: Read about type erasure https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html Basically, you're problem is that you're trying to implement B<Double> and B<String> (because od D) at the same time, but at some point during compilation both these types are just plain B, so when you implement f(...), the compiler cannot understand what's your point.

Comment: @GhostCat Hi :) I had an idea. Closed before submitting :p

Comment: @Filip Malczak as far as I understand the compiler only replace the T and the < T > , and not a concrete type. like f(String),f(Double). so why the compiler fail to compile it?
also, if it replace f(String)/f(Double) with f(Object) so why any generic method work? method arguments in java are no-variance , so override should never work with generic interfaces. mmm...

Comment: @Aviad Shiber - I promise you that language reference and tutorial has all the answers.

Comment: @FilipMalczak so can you please guide me to that place? I could not explain it to myself, I am already familiar with this tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Complex inheritance like this is almost always a bad idea. The case you've run into is a prime example.  Strongly consider using composition instead:

```
class C {
  private final B<String> b = new B<String>() { @Override public void f(String s) {} };
  private final D d = new D() { @Override public void f(Double x) {} };
  void f(String s) { b.f(s); }
  void f(Double x) { d.f(x); }
}
```